# Float-ed outer div is not resizing to accommodate its children

Tags: html, css

Here is code, highly condensed:

```
<div style="float:left; border: 2px red solid; padding: 2px; margin: 2px;">
    <div style="width:50%; border: 2px green solid; padding: 2px;  margin: 2px;">
        <ul>
            <li>I_Would_Like_The_Outer_Div_To_Resize_To_Accomdate_This_Blob_Of_Text</li>
            <li>It's floated-ed because I'm using floating to implement a float layout.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the output.  I would like the outer div's width to expand so that the inner div contains the long blob of text.  Here's the output:

[image]

EDIT:

Wow.  I meant to say:

> The outer div is float-ed because I'm using floating to implement a table-free COLUMN layout.

Comment: Placing that in which element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `word-wrap:break-word`,

```
<div style="float:left; border: 2px red solid; padding: 2px; margin: 2px;">
    <div style="width:50%; border: 2px green solid; padding: 2px;  margin: 2px;word-wrap: break-word;">
        <ul>
            <li>I_Would_Like_The_Outer_Div_To_Resize_To_Accomdate_This_Blob_Of_Text</li>
            <li>It's floated-ed because I'm using floating to implement a float layout.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to wrap the long blob of text.  I want the outer div to get large enough accommodate the inner div fully encompassing the blob of text.  (Actually it's not nearly that long in my code; the code I posted was just to illustrate the idea, clearly.)

Comment: ok. i think width:50%; that is prob. just modify inner and outer div width. maybe your prb solve

Comment: In my actual code, I have a third div tag.  It is after the inner div tag.  It is floated to the right.  I use the `width:50%` to make it so both of the inner div's take up equal amounts of horizontal space.  I cannot change the width of the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving both DIVs `width: auto` and optionally set a `min-width`.

Comment: While your suggestion fixes the immediate issue it isn't compatible with the rest of my code.  Inside the outer div I have another div (so a third div) that is floated to the right.  I used the width of 50% to make sure both of the inner divs each take up 50% of the width of the outer div.  I used float: left; on the outer div to make it so the outer div doesn't expand to fill its parent.  Therefore I cannot change the width of inner div.